# How to avoid sonar issue for multiple for loop

Tags: java, sonarqube

How to modify below code in optimize way so that we can avoid sonar issue?

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(customerVoList)) {
    for (CustomerVO customerVO : customerVoList) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(customerVO.getCardVos())) {
            for (CardVO cardVO : customerVO.getCardVos()) {
                float amount = redemptionService.getFutureRedemableBalance(cardVO.getCardNo(), cardVO.getCurrentBalance());
                cardVO.setCurrentBalance(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sonar throwing this exception:

> Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 if/for/while/switch/try statements

Comment: Could you make the question more specific by providing the exact warning being given by Sonar and the line (number) being warned about? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this by removing both the `if` statements. You can just let the `for` loop over an empty list which would be equivalent to skipping the loop.

```
for (CustomerVO customerVO : customerVoList) {
    for (CardVO cardVO : customerVO.getCardVos()) {
        float amount = redemptionService.getFutureRedemableBalance(cardVO.getCardNo(), cardVO.getCurrentBalance());
        cardVO.setCurrentBalance(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is assuming that those lists can't be null. Of course, good practice would be to always return empty lists instead of null (another rule covered by Sonar), but we don't know the circumstances in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below tricks .

Write your nested loops in some another methods and call the method with arguments .

Comment: Your second example wouldn't make any difference on the hierarchal depth and only serves to make things less readable. In general, you shouldn't go out of your way to make Sonar happy if it actually makes your code less readable. There are many cases where Sonar thinks that something is complex, while it's still perfectly readable by any human looking at it, due to the way things are structured.